# mktime returns wrong timestamp (off by a whole month)

Tags: c, date, time, utc, mktime

I use `mktime` to create a unix timestamp from my current local time:

```
#include <time.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  struct tm info;

  // 16.05.2014
  info.tm_mday = 16;
  info.tm_mon = 5;
  info.tm_year = 114; // Years since 1900

  // 08:00:00 Uhr
  info.tm_hour = 8;
  info.tm_min = 0;
  info.tm_sec = 0;

  // Convert to Unix timestamp
  info.tm_isdst = -1;
  time_t timestamp = mktime(&info);
  printf("Timestamp: %i", timestamp);
}
```

This gives me:

> 1402898400

When converting this back to a human readable time (via some website) this translates to:

> 16.06.2014 08:00:00

As you can see this is one month off from what I expected (put in May (5), got out June (6)).
Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> #### C11 7.27.1 Components of time
>
> ```
> int tm_sec; // seconds after the minute — [0, 60]
> int tm_min; // minutes after the hour — [0, 59]
> int tm_hour; // hours since midnight — [0, 23]
> int tm_mday; // day of the month — [1, 31]
> int tm_mon; // months since January — [0, 11]
> int tm_year; // years since 1900
> int tm_wday; // days since Sunday — [0, 6]
> int tm_yday; // days since January 1 — [0, 365]
> int tm_isdst; // Daylight Saving Time flag
> ```

`tm_mon` starts with `0`, not `1`. So the value of `5` means it's June, not May.

Comment: 5 means June not April

Comment: Wow, so the days start at 1, the months at 0? Argh!

Comment: @Boris argh indeed. This kind of thing make you debug for a day.